# Templating: what is the best way to display list of items with separators?

Tags: php, html, template-engine, templating

Let's say I have an array of data which I want to display as a list:

```
$goods = [
    ['title' => 'First item', 'description' => 'First item description'],
    ['title' => 'Second item', 'description' => 'Second item description'],
    ['title' => 'Third item', 'description' => 'Third item description']
];
```

And the following view:

```
<div class="good-block">
    <h1>{{ $good['title'] }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $good['description'] }}</p>
</div>
```

Now I want to display all the items using `<hr>` as a separator.

Therefore, the final view is as follows:

```
@foreach ($goods as $good)
    <div class="good-block">
        <h1>{{ $good['title'] }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $good['description'] }}</p>
    </div>
    <hr />
@endforeach
```

The problem is that, obviously, the separator will be displayed after the last item, not only between the elements. In the case of simple arrays `implode` can be used as a tool for splicing.

But how to use this approach in the template files? Is there a different approach, allowing to keep the code clean and logical, without adding unnecessary conditions like checking the current element is not last element of an array?

Thanks!

Comment: If you didn't want PHP to handle this, you could use `CSS` to set the `display` property of the last `.good-block`'s `<hr/>` element to `none;`, something like `.good-block:last-child > hr { display:none; }` (`CSS` people feel free to correct this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple trick is to keep a $counter, like so:

```
@$counter = 0;
@foreach ($goods as $good)
    @if ( $counter > 0 ) print '<hr />';
    <div class="good-block">
        <h1>{{ $good['title'] }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $good['description'] }}</p>
    </div>
    @$counter++
@endforeach
```

Now your hr will only appear before your entry, but it skips the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Blade:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#loops

```php
@foreach ($goods as $good)
    <div class="good-block">
        <h1>{{ $good['title'] }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $good['description'] }}</p>
    </div>
    @if (!$loop->last)
    <hr />
    @endif
@endforeach
```

however, if you're not using blade, you can use a key variable in the foreach loop like this:

```php
@foreach ($goods as $index => $good)
    <div class="good-block">
        <h1>{{ $good['title'] }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $good['description'] }}</p>
    </div>
    @if ($index < count($goods) - 1)
    <hr />
    @endif
@endforeach
```